# Python: setting an array equal to portions of another array so that both change together

Tags: python, list, pointers

What I want to do is have a list a = [0,1,2,3,4] and have a list b = [a[0], a[1], a[2]] (I don't want list b to contain all the items present in list a). Then if I do a[0] = 5, I want b[0] to equal 5 as well. Is this even possible to do in python, and if so, how can I implement this?

Comment: You may be able to get your code working like that but it won't be working the way you thin under the hood. There are no pointers in Python. If you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve by this you may get higher quality answers.

Comment: you could have both the arrays pointing to same base address.

Comment: You said: `I don't want list b to contain all the items present in list a` but also `if I do a[0] = 5, I want b[0] to equal 5 as well.` ? I don't catch your mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit** of course you should try slicing first https://www.oreilly.com/learning/how-do-i-use-the-slice-notation-in-python

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]

a[:3]
Out[26]: [0, 1, 2]

a[:3][0]
Out[27]: 0

a[0] = 5

a[:3][0]
Out[29]: 5
```

if you need elements in a order/sequence that can't be done with slice notation, then you could resort to my 
**origonal ans:**

if you don't mind the extra paren you can make `b` a function instead:

```
b = lambda : [a[0], a[1], a[2]]

b()
Out[12]: [5, 1, 2]

b
Out[13]: <function __main__.<lambda>>

b()[0]
Out[14]: 5
```

your IDE auto code checker may not like naming lambda's

then just def:

```
def b():
    return [a[0], a[1], a[2]]
```